# Can't Find my (encrypted) home folder in Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, lubuntu

I encrypted my home folder during installation, now I can't see the computer folder which I think should contain etc var and other folders. I need to get to the www/html/ everything works nice on terminal but i need some graphical interface

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ecryptfs-recover-private`.

1. Boot into your live CD, preferably an Ubuntu one of a newer version
2. Mount the partition containing your home directory (either your root partition, or your `/home` partition if you have one)
3. In your terminal, navigate to the directory containing your home directory (should be something like `/media/PARTITION_UUID/home`)
4. Run `ecryptfs-recover-private USERNAME`. It should prompt you with a few questions, and if it's successful, it will return a directory to which your home folder is mounted read-only. (e.g. `/tmp/ecryptfs.Jd7xE2Bd`)